# How to publish AWS SNS data to MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS/Database.
Since i am completely beginner to this, any suggestions will be appreciated.
Currently in the project it has been planned like data from AWS database will be pushed using SNS HTTP fanout to external MySql Database.
**NOTE :

1.The data will be pushed by the Client using AWS SNS**

**2. We have no access to the AWS account nor we are planning to have a AWS account.**

**3. External MySql database is a private database running on Linux Server** 

I have gone through the Official documentation of AWS SNS, and also some websites. This is all i found :

1. Use external applications like Zapier to map the data.
2. Develop some application to map the data.

   Is it like using a Servlet application in the receiver side to update the table, or is there any other methods?

   AWS DB -----> SNS -----> _________  -----> External MySql DB

Thanks

Comment: "We have no access to the AWS account nor we are planning to have a AWS account" -- If you have no account - then AWS Services will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot have an AWS Account, you can have your own web server consume the SNS Messages. SNS can deliver messages to an HTTP/HTTPS endpoint in a predefined structure. Read more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html). You can enable such an endpoint on your own server and share your server URL with the AWS Account owner. They can create a subscription from their SNS topic to your endpoint.

For setting up this endpoint, there are many options. [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) is one such popular framework to quickly implement HTTP APIs.

Comment: Thank you very much. You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, option two would be more suited, or at least first to be  considered. For that option you would have have to develop a **lambda function** which would [receive data from SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html), re-format if needed and upload it to MySQL. So your architecture would look like:

```
Data--->SNS--->Lambda function---> MySQL
```

Depending on the amount of incoming data to the SNS, you may add **SQS queue** as well to the mix, to **buffer** the records and enable **fun-out** architecture. For example:

```
               /---> SQS queue 1---> Lambda function 1---> MySQL
Data -->SNS --/ 
              \
               \--- SQS queue 2 ---> Lambda function 2, EC2 instance, Container ---> Other destination
```

Other solutions are possible. But I would first consider the above, before looking into other ways.

Comment: Just a small clarification :
1. Do we need AWS account to use lambda functions?
2. The above question is because, we have no access to AWS and also we have no AWS account. The data is sent using SNS by the client.

Comment: @Maddy26 To create the function you need aws account. But if you don't have AWS account, how do you get SNS?

Comment: I see. Then your question has not much to do with AWS. Should made it clear in the question that you are not using AWS services, or can't use them.

Comment: I am Sorry, i updated the question. Is there any way to update the database without using AWS?

Comment: @Maddy26 I think its too general if it does not involve AWS. There can be many solutions with various technologies, produces and architectures to achieve your outcome. And all will be valid and no answer will be "the correct one".

Comment: Could you provide with any one of the solutions?

Comment: @Maddy26 I already provided AWS based solution which was based on original question which did not exclude AWS.